# FFMpeg. Add frames black front and back video with audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have two valid ways to add black before and after video:

```
ffmpeg -i testa444.mov -f lavfi -i "color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25" -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [main]; [1:v] trim=end_frame=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [pre]; [1:v] trim=end_frame=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [post]; [pre][main][post] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [out]" -map "[out]" -c:v qtrle -c:a copy -timecode 01:00:00:00 test12.mov

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25:d=1 -i testa444.mov -filter_complex "[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=5 [blackstart]; [0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=3 [blackend]; [blackstart] [1:v] [blackend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[out]" -map "[out]" -c:v qtrle -c:a copy -timecode 01:00:00:00 test16.mov
```

I prefer the second.
What I do not get to do is add the audio from video test444.mov
Does anyone know how I do it?
I made many attempts but I have not got

Comment: I can add an answer, but I will need to see the complete console output from your second command; otherwise I would have to make some assumptions about your input and `ffmpeg` build.

Comment: Both the second and the first work well with the image but does not give the audio video output testa444.mov. I also need to know how to get audio.

Comment: Console output:

Comment: I can not give the console output because it has character limit and will not let me. Not if there's a method to include the console output.